# How much does adrenaline/warming up effect strength performance?

Tags: strength, warm-up, performance, athletic-performance

Warming up is important for safety reasons, but I'm not asking about that. I would like to know how much ‘psyching yourself up’ or being pumped with adrenaline affects an athlete's performance in strength activities.

[Tom Boyle's example](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/extreme-fear-superhuman/) comes to mind. In his case, this weight lifter lifted half a 3,000-pound car off the ground, so as to save a trapped cyclist. He damaged his body as a result, tragically. The article doesn't go into extensive detail about how this was possible, and how much was related to adrenaline.

I would like to ask for more details on this subject. How big a role does adrenaline play in performance? Have there been tests measuring performance without warm-ups versus with warm-ups?